# Use c# windows application projects in a web application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows

How can I use some projects I created using Visual C# 2010 in a Web Application.

I want the projects all separated in the web application if possible

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply separate the parts of the application that are specific to Windows from the parts that are not specific. Similarly, separate the parts that are not web-specific from the rest. Put that parts not specific to any particular technology into one or more common class library projects.

Hint: these common class library projects should build with no references to System.Windows.Forms or to System.Web. Otherwise, they may not be general enough.

Answer (score 1):

Are those projects class libraries? Most probably  you can use them (except the windows application projects) as it is in the web application by adding references of them in the web application.

You can separate out the classes in those windows application in the class libraries and then you should be able to add the class libraries in the Web application which would use the class libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking to rewrite the application and would prefer a quick start on creating the web application then I'd investigate how useful the tool offerings are in this area.

A quick look on [SharpToolbox](http://sharptoolbox.com/categories/rad-dev-automation) reveals two candidates:

1. [suite4.net](http://www.suite4.net/products/default.aspx)
2. [Visual Web GUI](http://www.visualwebgui.com/)

I am not affiliated with any of these nor have I tried them and so cannot vouch for any of the claims they make about their products, but it might be worth trying them out.